# Devise, undefined local variable or method current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have `Project` controller and rspec file for it. I'm usig `current_user` helper in this way:

```
# projects_controller_spec.rb

describe "user signed in" do
  before(:each) { sign_in @user }
  after(:each)  { sign_out @user}

  describe "GET index" do      
    it "assigns all projects as @projects" do
      project = FactoryGirl.create(:project, :user => current_user)
      get :index, {}, valid_session
      assigns(:projects).should eq([project])
    end
  end
  ...
end
```

The helpers `sign_in` and `sign_out` seem to work fine but I'v got an error on `current_user`:

```
undefined local variable or method `current_user'
```

What might be a problem, how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's normal. You should create a User instance. You could use let like this :

```
# projects_controller_spec.rb

describe "user signed in" do

  let(:user) {FactoryGirl.create(:user)}
  before(:each) { sign_in user }
  after(:each)  { sign_out user}

  describe "GET index" do      
    it "assigns all projects as @projects" do
      project = FactoryGirl.create(:project, :user => user)
      get :index, {}, valid_session
      assigns(:projects).should eq([project])
    end
  end
  ...
end
```

You know than the current_user is user ...

You don't need to sign out your use after each spec.